# Finding the inverse of (x-1) in $F=Z_{5} / (f(x))$

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

I am trying to find the inverse of $x-1$ in $F=Z_{5} / (f(x))$

Where $f(x) = x^3 + x + 1$

So performing the EEA

$1 = ((x-1) - (3)(2x-2))$
$1 = ((x-1) - ((x^3 + x + 1) - (x - 1)(x^2 + x + 2)(2x-2))$
$1=((x-1)(1-(x^2+x+2)(2x-2))-(x^3+x+1)(2x-2)$
$1=(x-1)(3x^3+x+2)-(x^3+x+1)(2x-2)$

so the inverse of $(x-1)$ is $(3x^3+x+2)$
but when I multiply the two together I don't get $1$

Could someone help me out? i've performed the EEA multiple times and am still getting the same answer..

Comment: $1=(x-1)(3x^3+x+2)-(x^3+x+1)(2x-2)$ cannot be right because the term in $x^4$ does not vanish.

Comment: Your very first step is wrong. You wrote $1 = (x-1) - (3)(2x-2)$. That is wrong. Let's check: $(x-1)-(3)(2x-2) = x-1-6x+6=5-5x$ which is $0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$, not $1$. ... If this is supposed to be the Extended Euclidean Algorithm, then you should have started with some divisions (division with remainder, aka, "long division"). I think that you must have made a mistake in those division steps.

Comment: If you want help finding your mistake then please show ALL of your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PolynomialExtendedGCD%5Bx-1,x3%2Bx%2B1,x%5D) gives this over $\mathbb Z$, which you can easily check:
$$
3 = (-x^2 - x - 2)(x-1)+(1)(x^3+x+1)
$$
In $F$, dividing by $3$ is multiplying by $2$, and so in $F$ we get this:
$$
1 = 2(-x^2 - x - 2)(x-1)
$$
Therefore, the inverse of $x-1$ in $F$ is $2(-x^2 - x - 2)=3x^2+3x+1$.

Comment: I'm so lost... Why are we dividing by 3? how did you get an x^2 term and not x^3?

Comment: ok so I do I just divide  by x^3+x+1 then? I don't see why im dividing by 3